# ¿Cómo obtener el día del año desde un datetime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Básicamente, lo que necesito es formatear un `datetime` para obtener el día del año y mostrarlo en una [etiqueta](http://www.thereadystore.com/food-and-water-storage/3330/how-to-figure-out-your-food-storage-manufacture-date/). Es decir, si tengo por ejemplo una `datetime` cualquiera:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 16, 11, 8, 2, 620935)
```

Quiero convertirlo al siguiente formato `AÑO+DIA_DEL_AÑO`:

```
10229
```

El ejemplo anterior significa que el producto fue producido el año 20**10** en el **229**avo día del año.

¿Existe alguna función, método o librería que me ayude a obtenerla?

Comment: Lo que pides **no** es el día juliano: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Día_juliano

Comment: @astrojuanlu ¿cual es el nombre correcto entonces? Pensé que se le decía asi

Comment: Yo creo que es "día del año" sin más, ¿no?

Comment: @astrojuanlu creo que si, lo edito asi queda mas claro

Comment: El nombre correcto para lo que se pregunta es día o fecha ordinal, en inglés, [ordinal date](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Fecha_ordinal)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Teniendo un objeto `datetime`, puedes obtener el día del año de la siguiente manera:

```
import datetime

# por ejemplo, si quieres el día de hoy
dt = datetime.datetime.now()

# simplemente con el método `strftime`
print (dt.strftime("%y%j"))
```

Cuya salida —para el día en que ha sido escrita esta respuesta— es: `15350`

Ahora bien, en caso de querer generar este texto para una fecha cualquiera, dependerá del formato de entrada de la fecha. Por ejemplo:

```
import datetime

# por ejemplo, para una fecha cualquiera
dt = datetime.datetime.strptime("2006/11/21 16:30", "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")

# aplicando strftime,
# este print dará como resultado: 06325
print (dt.strftime("%y%j"))
```

Si quieres algo más completo, se puede usar también la estructura [struct_time](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.struct_time), uno de cuyos miembros (`tm_yday`) es precisamente el día del año.

```
import datetime

# por ejemplo, si quieres el día de hoy
dt = datetime.datetime.now()

# obtienes la tupla (estructura struct_time).
tupla = dt.timetuple()
print (dt.strftime("%y") + str(tupla.tm_yday))
```

---

**Observaciones**:

- Los `print` tienen su argumento encerrado en paréntesis, para que sean compatibles con Python 3.x.

Comment: Muy completa la respuesta, pero el día del año *no* es el día juliano. Preguntad a un astrónomo :)

Comment: Nicolás, lo pruebo y te confirmo aunque esta bastante entendible

Comment: Jajaja, @astrojuanlu. Bueno, me he dejado llevar por la traducción literal de `day of the year`. Mejor lo edito.

Comment: No es por ser pesado, pero lo has editado al revés: lo que has calculado es el día del año, no el día juliano. Es que mi trabajo involucra convertir fechas astronómicas xD

Comment: @astrojuanlu, tienes toda la razón. Me temo que estaba confundido. Editaré apropiadamente entonces.

Comment: @Nicolás funciona en Python 3.x?

Comment: Para que funcione en Python 3.x, debes escribir entre paréntesis lo que le entregas al print: `print (dt.strftime("%y%j"))`. Lo agregaré a la respuesta.